# Multiple boxplot for different variable using same facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am new to R.
I want to plot 4 box plots for 4 continuous variables and present them in the same plot. I am trying to present the boxplot for each variable in 2 study groups while using facet_wrap in ggplot.

dividing variable is: cognitive_groups (has two values 0, 1)
the 4 variables are: memory (presented here), attention, exeuctive and language domains.
here is the code,

```
cogdb_bl%>%
filter(!is.na(cognitive_groups))%>%
ggplot(aes(x=memory))+
geom_boxplot(aes(y=""))+
facet_wrap(~cognitive_groups)+
theme_bw()+
coord_flip()+
labs(title="Cognitive domains in baseline groups",
   x="Z score")
```

Here is the output,
How do I present the other variables alongside the memory?
THANKS!

Comment: Hi Sari - could you include a small sample of your data with your code?

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first question here, I don't know how to send a data sample.m

Comment: @Carl 
I have 3000 participants (rows) - for each one there are 5 variables (columns)
ID, memory score, attention score, language score, exeuctive score and cognitive score.
Whereas, only cognitive score is a factor (0,1) - so I want to show box plots for each variable between the two cognitive groups. 
I tried to use Facet_wrap (ggplot2) to divide the data according to cognitive score. 
But I am not able to put all boxplot in the same plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? A `tribble` by the way is a nice way to create a minimal sample of data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~participant, ~memory, ~attention, ~language, ~executive, ~cognitive,
  "A", 2, 5, 2, 2, 0,
  "B", 2, 2, 5, 2, 1,
  "C", 2, 2, 2, 2, 0,
  "D", 2, 3, 2, 6, 1,
  "E", 2, 2, 2, 2, 0,
  "F", 2, 2, 8, 2, 0,
  "G", 2, 4, 2, 2, 1,
  "H", 2, 2, 7, 2, 1
) |>
  pivot_longer(c(memory, attention, language, executive), 
               names_to = "domain", values_to = "score") |>
  ggplot(aes(domain, score)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~cognitive) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = "Cognitive domains in baseline groups",
    y = "Z score"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: WOW! thank you, sir,
It looks amazing, exactly how I want to present it. 
So I replaced cog_grp with cognitive_status (the variable name in my DB) 
But the results seem to be the same, should I adjust more stuff? 
Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!

Comment: If your data frame input is in the same structure as my `tribble`, and adjusting for any column name changes, then the above code from `pivot_longer` onwards should work. (PS please accept the answer if it helps!)

Comment: `pivot_longer` is key because it arranges the 4 score columns into two new columns (domain and score), and this makes the faceting possible.